# How to hook into onClick method inside a method using frida

Tags: android, frida

I want to change behaviour of onClick method by hooking with frida. 
The code I used is

```
Java.perform(function() {
    console.log("[*] START...")
    var mClass = Java.use("sg.vantagepoint.uncrackable1.MainActivity")
    mClass.a.onClick.implementation=function() {
        console.log("[*] Clicked ")
    }
})
```

iam getting error

```
TypeError: cannot write property 'implementation' of undefined
    at [anon] (../../../frida-gum/bindings/gumjs/duktape.c:57636)
    at /uncrackable1.js:6
    at frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:11
    at E (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:346)
    at frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:298
    at frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:11
    at frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:278
    at /uncrackable1.js:11
```

source code is

```
    private void a(String str) {
        AlertDialog create = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        create.setTitle(str);
        create.setMessage("This is unacceptable. The app is now going to exit.");
        create.setButton(-3, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to hook the wrong class - most likely because you are using Jadx for decompiling the wrong settings and no knowledge on Java classes.

If you are using **Jadx** for decompiling the APK file make sure to **disable** the setting **Inline anonymous classes** to see the real class name a method belongs to.

The Method `onClick()` belongs to the anonymous inner class created by `new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()` and not to `sg.vantagepoint.uncrackable1.MainActivity` - hence you are trying to hook the wrong class. The method `a(String)` it is used in is totally irrelevant for hooking. Anonymous inner classes have their own class name based on the outer class appended by `$` and a number.
Therefore the correct class name may be `sg.vantagepoint.uncrackable1.MainActivity$1` or `sg.vantagepoint.uncrackable1.MainActivity$2`, depending on how many other anonymous inner classes are present.

Additionally something like `mClass.a.onClick` is not possible, as there is no method inside a method (`a` is a method and `onClick` is a method).

In the end you may end up with the following frida code:

```
Java.perform(function() {
    console.log("[*] START...")
    var mClass = Java.use("sg.vantagepoint.uncrackable1.MainActivity$1")
    mClass.onClick.implementation=function() {
        console.log("[*] Clicked ")
    }
})
```